# SQL Query to split the string

Tags: sql, db2

I have table with column called "Seat Number". Values will be like `ABCD 4F A083,XYZ 3F 7098`. I want to split the string in to three separate string and need to compare with other table column value. I have tried like this but getting error, Can you any one help me on this?

Query :

```
SELECT A.EMPLOYEE_NAME,
       Substr(A.EMPLOYEE_CODE, 1, 6) AS "EMPLOYEE_CODE",
       A.EMPLOYEE_NOTES_ID,
       A.ACCOUNT_SECTOR,
       A.ACCOUNT_INDUSTRY,
       A.GLOBAL_CLIENT_NAME,
       A.PROJECT_DB_ID,
       A.PROJECT_NAME,
       B.WORKPLACE_INDICATOR,
       B.SPACE_ID,
       C.FLOCATION,
       D.FBUILDING
FROM   DB2INST1.TMP_PIR A
       INNER JOIN DB2INST1.BluePages B
               ON Substr(A.EMPLOYEE_CODE, 1, 6) = B.EMP_CODE
       LEFT OUTER JOIN DB2INST1.TPARAM_LOCATION C
                    ON A.LOCATION_AS_PER_BLUEPAGES = C.FLOCATION
       LEFT OUTER JOIN DB2INST1.TPARAM_BUILDING D
                    ON LEFT(B.SPACE_ID, Charindex('', B.SPACE_ID) - 1) = D.FBUILDING
```

values are separated by "space bar"

Comment: Seat Number= SPACE_ID

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Hi I am using DB2 and I am new it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to figure out the key values that we need. So you need to locate the location of each space (first and second occurences).

```
first_occurence_location = CHARINDEX ( ' ' ,Space_ID) 

second_occurence_location = CHARINDEX ( ' ' , Space_ID, CHARINDEX ( ' ' ,Space_ID))
```

Next you need to find the values between the spaces:

```
first_value = SUBSTRING(Space_ID, 0, first_occurence_location)

second_value = SUBSTRING(Space_ID, first_occurence_location, second_occurence_location - first_occurence_location)

third_value = SUBSTRING(Space_ID, second_occurence_location, len(Space_ID)-second_occurence_location)
```

so the final result would be:

```
select 
   SUBSTRING(Space_ID, 0, CHARINDEX ( ' ' ,Space_ID) ) as first_value, 
   SUBSTRING(Space_ID, CHARINDEX ( ' ' ,Space_ID) , CHARINDEX ( ' ' , Space_ID, CHARINDEX ( ' ' ,Space_ID)) - CHARINDEX ( ' ' ,Space_ID) ) as second_value,
   SUBSTRING(Space_ID, CHARINDEX ( ' ' , Space_ID, CHARINDEX ( ' ' ,Space_ID)), len(Space_ID)-CHARINDEX ( ' ' , Space_ID, CHARINDEX ( ' ' ,Space_ID))) as third_value
from table
```